# Timeout connecting to SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception, ado.net, sql-server-express

my application is asp.net MVC3, I am using SQLExpress 2012.  I get the following error

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

when I try to run the following:

```
public static List<vw_MasterView> GetMasterView(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
{
    if (fromDate == null) fromDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    if (toDate == null) toDate = DateTime.Now;
    using (DALDataContext ctx = new DALDataContext())
    {
        var q = from c in ctx.vw_MasterViews
                where c.FirstVisitDate >= fromDate && c.LastVisitDate <= toDate
                select c;
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

I did increase the connection time (server / advance properties) to 6000.

When I run the view from the designer (in SQL Server) I get the same error message, however when I run the query (in SQL server) it works fine, it took 54 seconds to excute.

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if there is an open transaction? sp_who(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) might be able to list all the processes holding a connection.

Comment: there are few sa (background and sleeping), only one user as runable.

Comment: In that case, I wonder what DALDataContext does ? Is it possible to share the implementation?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Why bother? This is EF ror LINQ2Sql, so it is a standard context. Want to learn modern data access, read up on entity framework.

Comment: Plus query execution plans. YOu may hit table scans due to missing indices which are really not helping (tons of locks).

Comment: @TomTom, thanks for the tip, but I guess in the end the answer was in the implementation of DALDataContext. Not sure what I missed here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default value of the `DataContext` class's `CommandTimeout` is set to 30 seconds. Any database queries taking a longer time to complete than 30 seconds (and as you wrote your is taking about 60) will throw a *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired Exception*.

If you look at the auto generated `DALDataContext` subclass you will a few partial method declarations, your point of interest should be `OnCreated` method. You can define the body of the `OnCreated` method in another partial class with the same full name as that of the auto generated class and set the desired timeout value there in the following way:

```
partial class DALDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.CommandTimeout = 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much tpeczek, excellent solution; it worked very well.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is NOT an answer, sorry. 30 seconds? This is NUTS as an answer. This type of query taking 30 seconds on a loaded system is like a Mercedes having a top speed of 40km/h and you telling it is a problem of the traffic laws. This is a query that in a table below 100 million records should take single digit seconds.

Comment: @TomTom Ok, real life example. In one of my projects there is linked server connection between SQL Server and Oracle and due to network organization the quries which use this link are always taking almost 2 minutes (application is also not allowed to connect the Oracle server directly) - many strange real life situation might happen due to strange requirements that you have no influence on. The question wasn't about optimizing his query (there is a possibility that it is just a crappy query of course) but resolving the timeout.

Comment: @tpeczek Yes, but that is the LAST one thing you change. And you look at query plans first. All this has not happened. All this is just "hey, improove the timeout, who the hell cares to check what the issue is".

Comment: @TomTom I'm not going to argue with you about the philosophy in which direction the answer should go. Nobody is forbiding you from providing another answer that will explain him how should he approached query optimization. At this point there is no information what his view actually does and if the query can take longer than 30s or not - and that wasn't his question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the connection timout of your DBContext:

```
ctx.CommandTimeout = 200;
```

Comment: No, he does not. "Get a faster machine" and "wait" are not valid answers here. Unless he has TONS of data, this query should not take 30 seconds to start with.

Comment: @TomTom disregarding the context he is working into, we are **answering the question**

Comment: No, you do not. YOu throw around a bad advice when you first would nail the problem. You work just by chance as outsources? QUaltiy regardless, it somehow works, so we get paid?